# Curl call works, but Python request call fails with [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to access a internal address with a self signed certificat. I do have access to the CA.
If I try with curl, there is no issue:

```
curl https://myhost.internal  --cacert ./mycert.crt
```

I get a 200

But if I try in python (same machine):

```
import requests
requests.get('https://myhost.internal', verify='./mycert.crt'
```

Then I get following error:

```
SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate
verify failed (_ssl.c:727)')
```

I try out of curiosity to call curl from python subprocess, and it works too.

If I do the request in python asking to ignore the cert it works, but this is not an option for security reason.

Any idea why  ?

Comment: What format is your certificate file in? Is it a PEM encoded certificate with a header and footer line, or is it binary?

Comment: It si a plain PEM file with header and footer.

Comment: This would be easier to diagnose if we had access to both the ca certificate `mycert.crt` and the certificate presented by `myhost.internal`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found the reason.
I was not providing the root CA, only an intermediate one.
It seems that providing the -cacert option to curl do not make it verify the full chain while it does to python.